# Message received when Window gets activated

Tags: windows, winapi, directx

I'm trying to pause a DirectX game when the windows loses focus, but the messages seem to be inconsistent.

When using windows mode WM_SETFOCUS and WM_KILLFOCUS messages are received and everything works fine, but these messages are not received when using full screen mode. WM_NCACTIVATE is received when using full screen mode and it works fine, but in window mode is not received when the application is minimized from the taskbar. WM_ACTIVATEAPP also is not received in several cases.

Is there any consistent way of handling the gain/lose focus problem? I want to use only one message that is received in both full screen and window mode.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [WM_ACTIVATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for that.

Comment: Same problem as with WM_NCACTIVATE, when I minimize the window with the mouse from task bar the message is received twice, once with wParam inactive and once with wParam active...